# Is this a bug with the Angular Bootstrap date picker?

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap

If I have an Angular bootstrap date picker with a format of "DD/MM/YYYY" and hide it with an ngIf it defaults back to a format of "MM/DD/YYYY" when it is shown again.

```
<button (click)="show = !show">{{ show ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }}</button><br>
<input bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY' }" type="text" [(bsValue)]="date" *ngIf="show">
```

See this StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwa2fs

Can anybody think of a work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One workaround would be to only hide the datepicker in DOM, instead of destroying/recreating it. So, instead of `*ngIf="show"`, `[class.hidden]="!show"` (and css: `.hidden { display: none; }`).

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eudgh3?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Since this is bootstrap, you can actually use `[class.d-none]="!show"` which is a bootstrap display utility for css property `display: none`. So, you don't have to redefine another block of css property again..

Comment: Works a treat in my form library https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t1wshi

Comment: Even better with class.d-none